# LiteIDE on ubuntu 20.10

Tags: ide, golang

I'm starting to play with go and thought the idea of an ide might be a nice throwback to the days of C++ programming.

The only one that seems to be open source and sort of maintained that I can find is LiteIDE, but I'm struggling to make it work.

The snap version installs, but I can't seem to edit the environment to suite my setup, nor can I work out how to make another environment (although it seems it should be possible).

I then tried the binary version (tgz file), but when I try and run that I get

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: xcb.
```

So, am I out of luck? Are there any other IDE's I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code is a lightweight but powerful source code editor which runs on your desktop and is available for Linux, macOS and Windows. It comes with built-in support for JavaScript, TypeScript and Node.js and has a rich ecosystem of xtensions for other languages (such as C++, C#, Java, Python, PHP, Go) and runtimes (such as .NET and Unity).

Visual Studio Code is the top upvoted IDE at [What are the best IDEs for the Go programming language?](https://www.slant.co/topics/5178/%7Eides-for-the-go-programming-language). One reason why is that Visual Studio Code has comprehensive support for the Go programming language is shown in the 2nd and 3rd screenshots.

To install Visual Studio Code in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu  open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```

The Extensions icon is the 5th icon which is highlighted in the vertical panel on the left side of Visual Studio Code. Go (golang.go) extension adds rich Go language support for Visual Studio Code. Code Runner extension runs code snippets or code files for multiple languages including Go in Visual Studio Code. To run a code snippet with Code Runner right-click the code and select *Run Code* as shown in the below screenshot. The output of the program is shown in the console at the bottom of Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Click the *Install* button to install missing Go analysis tools.

[image]

[image]